# Clicking on a "link"

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to click on a link which seems to be in a modal/hover, I think.  Initially I have to do a mouse over to the "Your Account" (see image below). I have that scripted using

```
option = driver.find_element(:class => "login-outer")
driver.action.move_to(option).perform
```

The problem I am having is clicking on the "Sign In" or "New User" links.

Below is the code I get when I use Firebug and click on Sign In.  Do I need to set focus on the dropdown before trying to click on the Sign In Link?

[image: website screen shot]

```
<div id="notloggedin" class="login-dropdown" style="opacity: 1; display: none;">
  <span style="padding: 0px 7px; display: block;">
    <a class="ajax-popup-link" href="https://www.wdev.rochester.edu/melioraweekendtest/account/login">Sign In</a>
```

Comment: Try to either focus the dropdown first or click the Your Account followed by Sign in click. I sometimes had to to one or the other and never could get one way or the other to work.Don't forget to put in a pause with the duel click option to account for load times.  Another thing you might try is to complete the action using the SeleniumHg GUI and read the script that is created. This can help figure out what action will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hover over the `Your Account` using `move_to`. Then again `move_to` `SignIn` option and then `click()` on it.

Comment: Interesting fact I ran into this morning.  The website is responsive.  Up to this point I have been maximizing the screen and running into these issues.  If I make the screen smaller (the browser on the left side of the screen) Then the Sign In link is clicked.  With the browser maximized it clicks on the tab behind the dropdown.  I might need to set focus on the dropdown or not maximize the screen until after I click on the link (a "sad" workaround).